# From a set of items, make a list of the items that has a normal distribution

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, statistics

I want to generate a list of items that follow a certain distribution; given a set f items and a distribution.

The way I do it now is inefficient. is there a better way to do this? Possibly without writing my own loops?

Currently, I loop through the items and I add the item x times.

```
s = ('a', 'b', 'c','d')
d = numpy.random.normal(5, 1, len(s)).round().astype(np.int)
result = []
for item, repeat in zip(s, d):
    for c in range(repeat):
        result.append(item)
```

Comment: What is i1, i2, i3, i4?

Comment: Well, in my case those are ids but they could be anything.

Comment: Your d is an array of floats. You are then using `repeat` which will be one these floats and then using `range(repeat)` which in invalid because range expects an integer

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that distribution values are integers.

Comment: don't you have to have probabilities instead in `d` ?

Comment: I was about to post answer but it was closed. You just have to do `result = np.repeat(s, d)`

Comment: Thanks @Bazingaa !

Comment: @BanishedBot having probabilities instead is another approach, but then, how to keep retrieving items from the set using those probabilities?

Comment: @ooo rejection sampling